# Mozilla Persona

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I know a lot of code, but I'm a complete scrub when it comes to xhr.setRequestHeader in html. I've set it up so a user can be logged in using Mozilla's Persona log in, but the console always returns errors:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length"
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) (sign-in, line 0)
```

I've set up the html pages... somewhat, but I'd love some help. my website can be found at https://agstp.tk and https://github.com/August712/august712.github.io. Thanks!

(Oh, and can someone explain to me what a header is? As I said, I'm new to this.)

Comment: Regarding "what's a header" - It's an HTTP header specifically. Some examples and general information are covered here - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039 . Search for more information regarding **HTTP header** in your favorite search engine.